# How to float 2 div's next to each other in IE8

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have two div's and I want to show them next to each other. In normal browsers it's no problem. In IE however, things are messed up:

[image]

The red squares point out the div's I'm talking about. The left div has the class "head_narrow", the image has the id "branche_header_image". 
My CSS looks like this:

```
.head_narrow {width:380px; float:left;}
#branche_header_image {float:right;}
```

I am sure that the width of the two divs together is smaller than the width of the wrapper. What's going on?

Comment: Tried adding `width` to the image CSS as well?

Comment: It's not working because the `DIV`'s are wider than the container so it's dropping the overflow to the next line. Make them smaller for IE and they'll float.

Comment: @Shadow Wizard: yes, that didn't help.
@Kyle Undefined: Unfortunately that's not the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add "width" in this id #branche_header_image {width:400px; float:right;}

Or use

```
display:inline;
```

for both divs instead of using float.

Comment: hmmm.. ok no problem click on this link for a demo : http://jsfiddle.net/rathoreahsan/AsyMH/  ----

Answer (score 0):

You could probably solve it more elegantly by displaying them as inline blocks inside a container div. But if you absolutely must use floats, place divs above and below your two floaters with style="clear: both;".