# html css float:right with img is not working fine

Tags: html, css, image, css-float, rights

**HTML**

```
<table class='titleStatus' id='title'>
        <tr>
            <td class='lefttop'></td>
            <td class='bar'>Punch Data
                <img class='minMaxClose' src='images/close.png'>
                <img class='minMaxClose' src='images/max.png'>
                <img class='minMaxClose' src='images/minimize.png'>
                <img class='minMaxClose' src='images/setting.png'></td>
            <td class='righttop'></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

**CSS**

```
.minMaxClose{float: right;}
```

**OutPut at IE**
[image]

**Whereas i need output like on Firefox**
[image]

Comment: Could you post the rest of your CSS/Upload to Jsfiddle?

Comment: Its too complex in combination of PHP, so i just simplify my problem :)

Comment: just guessing, not tested: wrap the "punch data" in a span and give it a defined width, e.g. 100px (or whatever fits your needs)

Comment: maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6439577/how-to-float-2-divs-next-to-each-other-in-ie8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML

```
<table class='titleStatus' id='title'>
        <tr>
            <td class='lefttop'></td>
            <td class='bar'>Punch Data
                        <!--[if IE]>
                             <div class='ico-wrapIE'>
                        <![endif]-->
                        <!--[if !IE]>
                             <div class='ico-wrap'>
                        <![endif]-->
                <img class='minMaxClose' src='images/setting.png'>
                <img class='minMaxClose' src='images/minimize.png'>
                <img class='minMaxClose' src='images/max.png'>
                <img class='minMaxClose' src='images/close.png'>
            </div>
            </td>
            <td class='righttop'></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

CSS

```
.ico-wrap{float:right;}
.ico-wrapIE {
  position: absolute;
  right: 2px;
  top: 2px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

apply float:left to all images first and then apply float:right to your container containing images

```
.bar img{
float:left;//for shifting alongside
}


.bar{
float:right;//for shifting entire division to right side
}
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/Am34U/3/ give bar a width of 800px or something, and say you put punch inside a span and give it a span of 300px and float left, and give the span that contains the images a span of 500px and float left too.

HTML

```
<table class='titleStatus' id='title'>
        <tr>
            <td class='lefttop'></td>
            <td class='bar'>
                <span id="punch">Punch Data</span>
                <span id="close">

                    <img class='minMaxClose' src='images/close.png'>
                    <img class='minMaxClose' src='images/max.png'>
                    <img class='minMaxClose' src='images/minimize.png'>
                    <img class='minMaxClose' src='images/setting.png'>
                </span>
            </td>
            <td class='righttop'></td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

CSS

```
.minMaxClose{
    float: right;
}
#close{
    background: purple;
    width: 400px;
    float: left;
}
#punch{
    background: orange;
    width: 300px;
    float: left;
}
.bar{
    width: 700px;
    background: blue;
}
```

Comment: mine case is complex i can't fix the width. i discover solution myself. Please check my anwser